# Image floating in questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Is it possible to float images here in Gaming.SE?

It seems the html style-attribute is completely disabled, any other way to do it?

What do I need it for? See my answer here as an example for the need for floating:
[What do the symbols next to the player names mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32973/what-do-the-symbols-next-to-the-player-names-mean/32982#32982)

Comment: Related request on Meta: [Can we get a way to wrap text around images?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99573)

Answer (score 2):

We don't feel the additional complexity this would incur is worth the minor benefit to a tiny handful of posts.

In pretty much every case, you can achieve the same result with simpler unfloated images (and remember unfloated images can "stack" next to each other left-to-right..).

Comment: Ok, I get your point with complexity. I don't understand though how I could achieve the same result with unfloated images in the above named question. (at least not without replacing the text with images, which would be bad for SEO and usability)